# How to show the selected options from a multi select drop down using selenium java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to show all the selected options from a multi select drop down list. But not getting the proper way to do this. Please help me on this.

Here is the html code for the drop down:

```
<select multiple id="fruits">
     <option value="banana">Banana</option>
     <option value="apple">Apple</option>
     <option value="orange">Orange</option>
     <option value="grape">Grape</option>
</select>
```

Here is the code i'm trying with:

```
public void dropDownOperations()
    {
        driver.get("http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2");
        Select DDLIST = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));
        DDLIST.selectByIndex(0);
        String currentvalue = DDLIST.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
        System.out.println(currentvalue);
        DDLIST.selectByIndex(1);
        String currentvalue1 = DDLIST.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
        System.out.println(currentvalue1);          
    }
```

I also tried with this code:

Here i'm getting this output:

> [[[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (69aee19e9922ca218ff47c0ccdf1bbbc)] ->
>   id: fruits]] -> tag name: option], [[[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP
>   (69aee19e9922ca218ff47c0ccdf1bbbc)] -> id: fruits]] -> tag name:
>   option]]

```
public void dropDownOperations1()
    {
        driver.get("http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2");
        Select DDLIST = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));
        DDLIST.selectByIndex(0);
        DDLIST.selectByIndex(1);
        List<WebElement> currentvalue1 = DDLIST.getAllSelectedOptions();
        System.out.println(currentvalue1);          
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach should work fine with a minor fix. `getAllSelectedOptions()` will return a List of selected options as WebElement. You need to iterate over the list to get the text from WebElement.

```
List<WebElement> selectedOptions = DDLIST.getAllSelectedOptions();
for (WebElement option : selectedOptions){
        System.out.println(option.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code, It will select one by one options from dropdown.

```
Select DDLIST = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));
DDLIST.selectByIndex(0);
DDLIST.selectByIndex(1);

List<WebElement> selectedOptions = DDLIST.getAllSelectedOptions();
for(int i=0; i<selectedOptions.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(DDLIST.getOptions().get(i).getText());
}
```

Comment: Actually i don't need to show all the available options present in the drop down list. Just wanted to show only the selected options. Suppose i have selected 1st and 2nd option from the dropdown. Then i want to show the text of only that 2 selected options.

Comment: Not able to up vote as i don't have 15 reputations right now. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
  List<WebElement> allSelected = select.getAllSelectedOptions();

      Iterator itr = allSelected.iterator();

      while(itr.hasNext()){

          WebElement item = (WebElement) itr.next();

          System.out.println(item.getText());
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
    System.out.println(DDLIST.selectByIndex(0).getText());
    System.out.println(DDLIST.selectByIndex(1).getText());
```

And so on. Instead of using a variable and trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select DDLIST = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));               
for(int i=0; i<DDLIST.getOptions().size(); i++)
   System.out.println(DDLIST.getOptions().get(i).getText());
```